# I want my app to run when the user clicks on the call button. How can I do that?

Tags: android

I want my app to run when the user clicks the call Button.
How can I do that?
I tried adding an intent-filter on activity, but it doesn't work

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
</action>
        <intent-filter
            >
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                >
            </action>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"
                >
            </action>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
                >
            </category>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"
                >
            </category>
            <data
                android:scheme="tel"
                >
            </data>
```

Comment: well adding intent filter in your activity of your manifest fille will not help, what you need is ['Broadcast receiver'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can register [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which will start your application with an [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) [Intent.ACTION_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) or [Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)
**[Here](http://bitgriff.blogspot.in/2013/01/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone.html)** you can find detail explanation